# Is it possible to convert Key BLOB to any other format using CAPI

Tags: cryptography

We use Key Blobs to export keys in public key cryptography. Is there any other format to export key pair using crypto API's.

So that the exported key storage type is compatible with other operating systems such as  Linux, unix etc

Comment: PKCS#12 isn't good enough for you ?

Comment: What language are you using?